# Delete command line after cursor position

Tags: conemu

Back in the MF days, it was accustomed to have the `END` key delete all text in the current line after the position of the cursor. This is very useful.

I couldn't find a specific ConEmu key and the GuiMacros don't seem up to the task.

Can this be accomplished in ConEmu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears clink already has this functionality defined by default.

The following line in `clink_inputrc_base` defines the key combo:

``` "\e``u": kill-line # ctrl+end ```

Answer (score 1):

Manipulation with command line is a shell function. But ConEmu is a terminal. It gets inputs from user and posts keys into a shell (console) input buffer. Terminal do not know anything what exactly the shell is doing with these keypresses.

So you only need to get proper shell. Try [clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/) for cmd, [PSReadLine](http://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) for PowerShell, or even bash from cygwin or MsysGit. That is quite clear described in ConEmu [disclaimer](http://conemu.github.io/#Disclaimer).